# Is it possible to set an arbitrary size for the Dash in unity?

Tags: 11.04, unity, unity-dash

What I mean is, can I set a size that more fits my liking? Like say, 50% of the screen, 25%, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with Unity in 11.04 or 11.10.

Comment: Mucos gracias Jorge, will file a bug report.

Comment: Is it possible in 11.10?